# How to create listview and title (dynamically) in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I am really confused, which among  GridView, Tableview or multiple listview to be used to develop a UI as shown in below image.

**I don't know how much list data (categories and its sub categories) is in web**. It is dynamically added from wed, and sent to my android app.
[image]

Please suggest me, what view is best for developing above UI.

Note: I want to make it programmatically.

Thank you in advance for your co-operation.

Comment: expandablelistview allows you to create lists by category and multiple sub-titles aggregated. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the image you have shown as an example is quite large and such an implementation would make for a cluttered UI on smaller screen sizes. That being said, the example you provided could be achieved in Android by using a `GridView`. Each major category (Automotive, Jobs, etc.) would be a grid item, with the sub element implemented as either a `TextView` or even a `ListView` within the grid item. Something like this:

[image]

As both @PedroHawk and @bryan mentioned, you could also use an `ExpandableListView`; in this scenario, the major categories (Automotive, Jobs, etc.) would be header items and the sub elements would be children of the header. Something like this:

[image]

However, with this implementation you would be limited to a one-dimensional list - that is you would not be able to have major categories next to each other as shown in your example.

With both of these implementations (`ExpandableListView` and `GridView`) you can dynamically add more elements as you receive data.

Answer (score 0):

Like PedroHawk said, ExpandableListView is an option. But also consider because of the screen size, you may not want to try and port the UI directly over. What about a single ListView with just the main categories and the user can drill down?